# Intelligencia URLRewriter - All *.html to *.aspx

Tags: urlrewriter.net

How do I tell URLRewriter to convert all *.html request into *.aspx requests?

The following works just fine for one page.

<rewrite url=”~/mypage.html” to=”mypage.aspx″ / >

How do I do it in one place for all pages?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this approach will be easy to maintain in the future. While this is easy to map as a wildcard, can you explain why this rule is needed?

For example, if you ever wanted to legitimately add a `.HTML` file to your solution, it would not be possible without an explicit `<ignore />` statement being added to your XML file.